# Given a block partition, look up open LUKS device

Tags: partition, luks

Given a block partition (such as `/dev/sdf3`), I'd like to look up an open LUKS device on that partition. E.g.:

```
$ some_command /dev/sdf3
/dev/mapper/luks-01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef
```

Or if no LUKS device is open on that partition, it would return nothing, or perhaps an error return value.

What command could be used to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

dev_name="$1"

test -z "$dev_name" && exit 2
test -b "/dev/${dev_name}" || exit 2
test -d "/sys/block/${dev_name}" || exit 2

majmin=$(<"/sys/block/${dev_name}/dev")
cryptsetup isLuks "/dev/${dev_name}" ||
    exit 1 # not correct with external LUKS header
dmsetup table |
    awk -v dev="$majmin" '$4 == "crypt" && $8 == dev { name=$1;sub(":$","",name); print name }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could `lsblk` do the job? For instance:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sda2
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda2           8:2    0 96.9G  0 part  
└─sda2_crypt 253:0    0 96.9G  0 crypt /home
```